# MFA in google identity platform with signInWithCustomToken not working

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-platform, multi-factor-authentication

MFA implementation with signInWithCustomToken is not working properly.

We are trying to implement the MFA using firebase and google identity platform for one of our php project. Since we don't depend on password login, we tried to use custom token authentication. While we tried to enroll to the second factor with first factor as signInWithCustomToken method it is showing an error 'MFA is not supported this first factor'. Also when we configured MFA for a user from the firebase interface and then using signInWithCustomToken return user credential successfully but infact as per the documentation we should get an auth error saying  'multifactor auth required'. Any one please help us to get a solution for this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.